# ifstream with wildcard

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

Does ifstream support something like :

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("/home/Desktop/*.txt*");
```

I am trying to do a similar operation and I get cann't open file. If I do `vim /home/Desktop/*.txt` I open the only file called help.txt1 but for some reason can't open it using ifstream.

Comment: If it did (which it doesn't), what file should it open if there is more than one match?

Comment: No; there is no such file with that name....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, how do you know? :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I looked and it wasn't there!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, full disclosure: I don't even have `/home/Desktop` directory…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Only because I've deleted it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no". The long answer is "no, it doesn't".

P.S. look at the `glob` function to get the list of files and process them one by one.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, Yes, I wouldn't guarantee it's available everywhere.

Comment: (not sure about posix, though)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of matching filename wildcards is called ["globbing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). You need to use [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) to get a list of files, then open each of them in turn.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the shell interprets your typed command `vim /home/Desktop/*.txt`.  It looks for files matching the pattern, and passes a list of them into the command arguments for the `vim` executable.

To do similar things from C++ on Unix, check out the [`glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/glob.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

`ifstream` does not support wildcards. You'll have to get all the files using `DIR` or something of the sort, then put everything with .txt in a list or array and loop over it calling `fopen` on each.